# Unable to find valid certificate path in jetty localserver of Guidewire

Tags: jetty, keystore, jsse, guidewire

I am unable to resolve this error of "Unable to find valid certificate path". I am setting all required system property e.g

```
System.setproperty(javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType,"jks")
System.setproperty(javax.net.ssl.trustStore,keystorePath)
System.setproperty(javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword,password)
```

I tried setting the VM arguments, but nothing is working for me. I am using Guidewire studio localServer (jetty).

Answer (score 2):

Jetty does not use JVM `javax.net.ssl.*` system properties to configure the SSL for specific connectors.

Look for anything in Guidewire studio that configures an `SslContextFactory` (the Jetty specific term for the SSL/TLS configuration belonging to a connector), and configure that.

Comment: Thnx for sharing this info. Can you please tell me if there is any xml or class for configuring this in jetty. @Joakim Erdfelt

Comment: Guidewire is likely using embedded-jetty, if so, then the configuration is 100% in the hands of Guidewire.  If Guidewire is shipped as a war, that you deploy in a Jetty Base with either the Jetty Distribution or Jetty Home, then the configuration is found in your Jetty Base start inis.

Answer (score 1):

The keystore would be taken from the JVM, so it kind of depends how you run your GW xCenter.

Since you ask about local Jetty the parameters you are looking for are

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\{pathToKeystoreOnYourMachine}\keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword={thePasswordToBeUsed}
```

In order to add those on `gwb runServer` level you would have to add a pass through prefix `gw.passthrough.` resulting in for example

```
gwb runServer -Dgw.passthrough.javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/Java/jdk1.8.0_74/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```